# clearing a particular bit in C for integer

Tags: c

```
typedef unsigned int  StatusCode;

StatusCode quality = 0;

#define PARTIALBIT 0x05

quality |= PARTIALBIT ;// I am setting a partial bit here
```

// ....

At other part of code I have to check if paritial bit is set and I have to clear it.
How do I acheive this in C ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll only give you a hint: Clearing a bit involves bitwise and and bitwise negation.

Comment: By the way, you do know that in the example in your question you set _two_ bits? Bits 0 and 2. You are not setting bit 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (quality & PARTIALBIT)
{
    // bit was set, do processing
    // ...
    // then clear the bit
    quality &= ~PARTIALBIT;
}
```

Also, if you have to set bit 5, then you're on the wrong way. If you want to set bit 5, use:

```
#define PARTIALBIT (1 << 5)
```

instead.

Comment: Actually you don't need to check if it's set. It's a superfluous operation.

Comment: I do read the comments, but I personally can't time-travel to the future. When I commented, there were no such comments in your code. You posted those comments 4 minutes later (probably due to my comment anyway...). Also, I upvoted your answer anyway, so try to not make such useless rude bold comments...

Comment: @m0skit0 first of all, thanks for the upvote. Second, the modifications were not inspired by your comment - I answered my first thought quickly, then I added some clarification. In no way did I mean to be rude.

Comment: Ok, no hard feelings, mate ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a bit x, you write:

```
val |= 1<<x
```

If you want to clear a bit x, you do:

```
val &= ~(1<<x)
```

If you want to inverse a bit x, you write:

```
val ^= 1<<x
```

Comment: `%` is the modulus operator.  I think you want exclusive or (`^`)

Comment: Hups! they are close on the keyboard !

Answer (score 0):

Alternative - use a bitfield union on the 'unsigned int StatusCode':

```
typedef union{
  unsigned intStatus;
  unsigned bitStatus:sizeof(unsigned);
} S_statusCode;
```